# Loop through 2d array in angularjs directive attribute

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a typeahead like this:

```
<input type="text" typeahead="pack.contributors for pack in packList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" />
```

The problem is that `pack.contributors` is itself an array. Is there some way in the typeahead attribute that I can have it iterate over pack.contributors to get the individual elements?

If not what is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to simply flatten the list and use that. If possible, use something like lodash's "flatten" function to easily do so.

```
$scope.allContributors = _.flatten(_.map($scope.packlist, 'contributors'));
```

Now use it in your template

```
<input type="text" typeahead="contributor in allContributors | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" />
```